# WinInet InternetConnect time outs when called from DLL

Tags: c++, dll, ftp, timeout, wininet

I have a small function for downloading a file from an ftp server, when I use as a standalonde application it works fine, but when I write a dll and I'm trying to inject that dll into a process then call the function the InternetConnect function gets timed out.

Here is my function:

```
extern "C" bool __declspec(dllexport)FileGet(const char* remote, const char* local)
{
    HINTERNET hInternet;
    HINTERNET hFtpSession;
    hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, FTPHOST, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, FTPUSER, FTPPASS, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0); // <--- The problem is here
    if(!(FtpGetFile(hFtpSession, remote, local, FALSE, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0)))
    {
        InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
        return false;
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe, the anti malware software does what it's supposed to do. But anyway, not specifying a calling convention for an exported symbol is wrong, no matter how you put it.

Comment: There's nothing in the logs of the AV.